# Haskell: Function using do notation and returning i.e. Integer value

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

I want to write a function that read some data using `getLine` and return i.e. a tuple (Integer, Integer) but using do-notation. Something like this (of course it doesn't work):

```
fun :: (Integer, Integer)
fun = do
    a <- read (getLine::Integer)
    b <- read (getLine::Integer)
    return (a, b)
```

Do I have to write my own monad for this? Is there any solution to not writing a new monad?

---

**EDIT**

So I can write `main` function that use `fun`, I think it's the only solution:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    tuple <- fun
    putStrLn (show tuple)

fun :: IO (Integer, Integer)
fun = do
    a1 <- getLine
    b1 <- getLine
    let a = read (a1)
        b = read (b1)
    return (a, b)
```

And above code works.

Comment: that is not possible, the type of fun has to be IO (Int, Int), you cannot leave the IO Monad.

Comment: Note that `return` means something quite different from what you may be used to in procedural languages. What you have there _is not a function_. In a function, the result that's "returned" is just the expression to the right of the `=`. By contrast, `return` always injects a value into some monad (you can see it quite plainly when typing `:t return` in GHCi), in this case the `IO` monad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You type of function should be

```
fun :: IO (Integer, Integer)
```

as mentioned by @kaan you should not try to get a mondic value (with side effects) out of the monad as that will break referential transparency. Running `fun` should always return same value no matter how many times it is run and if we use your type this will not happen. However if the type is `IO (Integer, Integer)` then it returns the same action every time you use that function and running this action actually perform the side effect of reading the values from the console.

Coming back to using you function. You can do that inside another `IO` monad like

```
main = do
  (a,b) <- fun
  print a
  print b
```

Although there are ways of getting things out of `IO` using unsafe functions but that is not recommended until you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you will need to give `fun` the type `IO (Integer, Integer)` instead of `(Integer, Integer)`. However, once you have resigned yourself to this fate, there are many ways to skin this cat. Here are a handful of ways to get your imagination going.

```
fun = do
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    return (read a, read b)

-- import Control.Applicative for (<$>)
-- can also spell (<$>) as fmap, liftA, liftM, and others
fun = do
    a <- read <$> getLine
    b <- read <$> getLine
    return (a, b)

fun = do
    a <- readLn
    b <- readLn
    return (a, b)

fun = liftM2 (,) readLn readLn

-- different type!
-- use in main like this:
-- main = do
--        [a, b] <- fun
--        foo
-- import Control.Monad for replicateM
fun :: IO [Integer]
fun = replicateM 2 readLn
```